# Avoiding Envelope charges on duplicate document if a timeout was reached.

Tags: duplicates, session-timeout, docusignapi

When I create an embedded document for signing, if the document times out after the 5 minutes allowed, how should I handle this? Just resend and basically create a new one? I've done this and it seems to duplicate envelopes... Is there a way to just renew the timeout, and re-direct the user to the same envelope? I've found similar posts but cant seem to find the exact answer to this... the goal of course avoiding a second envelope charge because they took longer than 5 minutes to sign the document. In creating a new envelope I'm sending the exact same document id, user etc.. but still seems to duplicate it on the back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "short lived URL" that you generate from the API does expire, and it is only good for a single use. If you need another URL due to timeout or 'finish later', you can use the API to request another URL. You do not need to create another Envelope.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic Scenarios/Embedded Signing.htm?Highlight=embedded